# Setting up a private pypi package?

Tags: python, git, pip, pypi

I am planning to create a python package which can only be used by team in my univ.I can host that on my university server.Is there any reference, guide or tutorial to do the same.I have developed pip packages previously but they were pushed onto the public space.
The idea is to put code on github (enterprised by my univ) and point the pip package to the git repo.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe just pointing the dependencies (requirements.txt/setup.py) of the packages that depends on this private package to that package's private github repo URL is enough. Add a line like this to your requirements.txt

```
-e git+ssh://git@github.com/example/example.git#egg=example
```

Comment: Thank you.But Is there any way i could make the end user job easier like "pip install <my_apckage_name> "--extra-index-url <my_server_url>""

Comment: Oh I see, you said the end users, can I assume they won't have access to the repo then?

Comment: It should just be another python package like django.They need not get into the code stuff.

Comment: May be something like PyPiCloud (https://pypicloud.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) does the trick for you other than that I don't have experience setting up a private PyPi server, so I'll just leave this this question for someone with more experience to answer. Hope you solve this soon.